Pipeline With Azure With Fastlane for Android play store ERROR
I'm French developper, i would create a pipeline for project.
I have project in Xamarin.Forms and i would create pipeline for build and deploy directly on playstore.
I would deploy in first time in internal deploy for test!
I use Fastlane for deploy.
I have already create Json key and autorised my user for api with Google Cloud i link my google cloud with my google play console.
This is my pipeline:
trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    jdkVersionOption: 1.11
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- script: |
    echo "Listing files in the output directory:"
    dir "$(outputDirectory)"
  displayName: 'Lister les fichiers dans le répertoire de sortie'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: downloadKeystore
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'AMO.keystore' 
  displayName: 'Télécharger le fichier keystore sécurisé'

- script: |
    echo "Signing the AAB file..."
    echo "Keystore Path: $(downloadKeystore.secureFilePath)"
    echo "Keystore Alias: $(YOUR_KEY_ALIAS)"
    jarsigner -verbose -keystore $(downloadKeystore.secureFilePath) -storepass $(apksignerKeystorePassword) -keypass $(apksignerKeyPassword) -signedjar "$(outputDirectory)/signed_com.AMOBeta.smarphone.aab" "$(outputDirectory)/com.AMOBeta.smarphone.aab" $(YOUR_KEY_ALIAS)
  displayName: 'Signer le fichier AAB'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(outputDirectory)/signed_com.AMOBeta.smarphone.aab'
    artifactName: 'SignedAAB'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
  displayName: 'Publier les artifacts de build'

# Télécharger la clé API Google Play Store
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: downloadApiPlayStoreJson
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'apiPlayStore.json'
  displayName: 'Download Google Play Store API credentials'

# Installer Ruby et Fastlane
- task: UseRubyVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=2.7'
    addToPath: true

- script: |
    gem install fastlane -NV
  displayName: 'Install Fastlane'

- script: |
    echo "Starting Fastlane deployment..."
    cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

    # Initialisation de Fastlane pour l'application
    fastlane supply init --json_key "$(downloadApiPlayStoreJson.secureFilePath)" --package_name "com.AMOBeta.smarphone"

    # Déploiement sur le track "internal"
    fastlane supply --json_key "$(downloadApiPlayStoreJson.secureFilePath)" \
      --package_name "com.AMOBeta.smarphone" \
      --aab "$(outputDirectory)/signed_com.AMOBeta.smarphone.aab" \
      --track "production" \
      --skip_upload_metadata true \
      --skip_upload_images true \
      --skip_upload_screenshots true \
      --verbose
  displayName: 'Deploy to Google Play Store using Fastlane'


During deploy I have that Error:


Can you run the same fastlane command to deploy Android play store on your local machine successfully?
